# PHP Fatal error on implementing interface methods

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

*Note for the zend folks: I am hoping this won't turn out to be a ZF specific question as I can see this is purely related to PHP (or in general an OOP) but added ZF tag just to see if there is something else I am missing*

I am creating a project in ZF 2 where I have a class which is implementing an interface called 
Service aware class `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`

Where this interface is very simple

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/zf2 for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2013 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Zend\ServiceManager;

interface ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * Set service locator
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     */
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator);

    /**
     * Get service locator
     *
     * @return ServiceLocatorInterface
     */
    public function getServiceLocator();
}
```

and my implementor class is this (I have removed everything else from this class for the sake of debugging, right now this is full length code in my class)

```
<?php
namespace FileServer\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\Di\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Data implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface{

    protected $sl;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->sl = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->sl;
    }

}
```

and I have an include statement in the index.php

```
include( 'E:\myproject\module\FileServer\src\FileServer\Service\Data.php' )
```

which is throwing PHP fatal error. Below is the complete error message

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   FileServer\Service\Data::setServiceLocator() must be compatible with
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface::setServiceLocator(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface
>   $serviceLocator) in
>   E:\myproject\module\FileServer\src\FileServer\Service\Data.php on
>   line 23

As you can see I am implementing both the getter and setter functions with proper signature but still getting the error. What I am missing/overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
use Zend\Di\ServiceLocatorInterface;
```

With:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
```

As thats the proper interface the method is expecting. Even though they have the same name, the namespace differs.